# Which .las classification codes and returns to use when creating DTM and DSM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, lidar, classification, las

I am trying to figure out what classification codes and returns that I should use to create DTM and DSM?

In my layer --> "BrooksCamp.lasd" I have these classification codes and returns:

[image]

[image]

(and then 26 to 31 reserved)

I am using the LAS Dataset to Raster tool.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, assuming your data classification conforms to the ASPRS LAS Classification guidelines, you'll use class 2 for ground as a bare earth DTM and first returns for a full feature DSM. There are buttons in the LAS Dataset properties window with predefined filters for just such a task.